# How to center vertically paragraph into Grid columns with fluid height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to center vertically a paragraph into col-md-6 knowing that height is relative to a responsive image height on 2nd col of the row.
It made me crazy...

```
<div class="container" style="background-color: red;">


    <div class="row" style="">


        <div class="col-md-6">

                <div class="text-center" style="background-color: white;">

                  <div class="">    
                    <p style="display: block;">Notre principale préoccupation est d’Identifier et évaluer les compétences, Evoluer l’Image et l’estime de soi, Développer les compétences et enfin assurer la fluidité entre compétences individuelles et compétences organisationnelles, et pour appuyer son action, PURE Solutions développe de nombreux partenariats avec de grandes entreprises et des associations de renommés. 
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>

        </div>


        <div class="col-md-6">


            <h3 class="heading text-center"> Solution</h3>

            <div class="thumbnail" style="margin-top: 8px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1400x1000" />
            </div>

        </div>


    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And where the CSS code you writing already ?

Comment: I only use css in html, and concerning the css for centering vertically, I tried a lot of version that normaly do that but it doesn't work and I haven't find any reason to write what doesn't work

Comment: Here is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22121783/how-do-i-specify-row-height-in-bootstrap-3/22122416#22122416 Just change vertical align to middle

Comment: Sorry, but it still don't work

Comment: No one can help with the css?????